# CSS: Aligning a paragraph element with a span containing SVGs

Tags: css, alignment

I have a `<p>` element which appears above a set of SVGs which are contained within a `<span>` element as you can see below. I would like the span containing the SVGs to align with the text 'Question 1'.

[image: alignment]

**Things which I have tried:**

- I found no margins or paddings that conflict with this alignment.
- The line-height is 0 for the paragraph text.
- Neither are set to `display: block;`, they are instead set to `display: inline;`

i have also included the a simplified version of the problem here (notice there is only one icon as the SVGs make it harder to follow): https://jsfiddle.net/qt3c2m49/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your paragraph should be given a `line-height` equal to the space you want it to take up (in this case 30px).

When you clear a float, you are essentially dropping it to a new line, so remove `clear: both;` from `.newTopicAnswerIcons`

Your icons all have a `margin-top` of 25px, this is pushing your icons down so make this 0 instead.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qt3c2m49/2/)